# Encoding and raw in R

Tags: r, character-encoding

I not sure if this is a bug or not. If I encode one of the characters to UTF-8 before converting to raw and back again, then the characters are not the same. I have set default encoding to "UTF-8" in RStudio.

```
rawToChar(charToRaw(enc2utf8("vægt")))
[1] "vÃ¦gt"

rawToChar(charToRaw("vægt"))
[1] "vægt"
```

Here is my sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Danish_Denmark.1252  LC_CTYPE=Danish_Denmark.1252    LC_MONETARY=Danish_Denmark.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=Danish_Denmark.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggthemes_2.2.1  TTR_0.23-0      lubridate_1.3.3 tidyr_0.2.0     skm_1.0.2       ggplot2_1.0.1   dplyr_0.4.3    
[8] stringr_1.0.0   dkstat_0.08    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.1      rstudioapi_0.3.1 magrittr_1.5     MASS_7.3-43      munsell_0.4.2    lattice_0.20-33 
[7] colorspace_1.2-6 R6_2.1.1         httr_1.0.0       plyr_1.8.3       xts_0.9-7        tools_3.2.2     
[13] parallel_3.2.2   grid_3.2.2       gtable_0.1.2     DBI_0.3.1        lazyeval_0.1.10  assertthat_0.1  
[19] digest_0.6.8     reshape2_1.4.1   curl_0.9.3       memoise_0.2.1    labeling_0.3     stringi_0.5-5   
[25] scales_0.3.0     jsonlite_0.9.17  zoo_1.7-12       proto_0.3-10
```

Comment: Confirmed on my Windows 10 machine but works fine on my Linux machine.

Comment: I think this is a Windows only issue.

Comment: This is an issue that I run into when using the different xml packages. Can anyone explain why enc2utf8 is needed before the charToRaw in the xml packages? You can't talk on behalf of the authors but I just want to understand why it's done and if I can suggest that enc2utf8 is removed without it causing a lot new issues.

Comment: What does `charToRaw("vægt")` return a Windows machine that shows the "problem"? I suspect `76 e6 67 74`. Can somebody confirm this, I don't have one nearby.

Comment: `charToRaw("vægt")` returns: `76 e6 67 74` and `charToRaw(enc2utf8("vægt"))` returns: `76 c3 a6 67 74`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's my basic understanding of what's going on.

First some encoding facts:

```
                  Encoding
character    UTF-8        CP1252
   v         76             76
   æ         c3 a6          e6
   g         67             67
   t         74             74
   Ã         c3 83          c3
   ¦         c2 a6          a6
```

Now the mechanics:

The Windows machine uses the [CP1252](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195054.aspx) encoding as can be seen from the `sessionInfo` output. So the `vægt` string in the R script is represented as the bytes `76 e6 67 74`. This is confirmed by `charToRaw("vægt")`. If we then convert it to UTF-8, we get `76 c3 a6 67 74`. The fact that these bytes represent UTF-8 is lost. Later `rawToChar()` converts these bytes back to a string, again assuming CP1252. Since `c3` is `Ã` and `a6` is `¦` in CP1252, we get `vÃ¦gt`.

On Mac and Linux, on the other hand, the default encoding is UTF-8 throughout and the encoding mismatches do not occur. I suspect, however, that the same phenomenon as on Windows could be triggered by explicitly changing/setting the encoding used by R.

I don't think this is a bug.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Now I think I understand this line in the help in `rawToChar`: _italic_ In either case it is possible to create a result which is invalid in a multibyte locale, e.g. one using UTF-8. _italic_ There is not much I can do about it then because I can't change the locale in Windows just for R (it's a computer I got from work, so I can't change the language)?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows in a non-UTF-8 locale, you can use [stri_encode](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/stringi/html/stri_encode.html) from the [stringi](https://stringi.gagolewski.com/) package to convert raw bytes back to the correct characters and encoding,

```
stringi::stri_encode(charToRaw(enc2utf8("vægt")), from = "UTF-8", to = "UTF-8")
[1] "vægt"
```

From the documentation of charToRaw (emphasis added),

> charToRaw converts a length-one character string to raw bytes. **It does so without taking into account any declared encoding**

Presumably `rawToChar` ignores original encodings in the same fashion. The stringi package on the other hand advertises

> stringi ... is THE R package for very fast, portable, correct, consistent, and convenient string/text processing in any locale or character encoding.